# (LUA) is there any way for me to cut a message and save it inside variables?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

i can use string.gsub(message, " ")
but it only cuts the words.

i searched on http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial but i cant find any solution for this there

how can i save these words into variables?
for example i have message = "fun 1 true enjoy"

and i want variables to have

```
var level = 1
var good = true
var message = "enjoy"
```

Comment: Which Lua Version? With Lua 5.3.5 it is quite simple to iterate with: ```for word in message:gmatch('%w+') do print('Do here what you want with:',word) end```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `string.match` to extract the fields and then convert them to suitable types:

```
message =  "fun 1 true enjoy"
level,good,message = message:match("%S+%s+(%S+)%s+(%S+)%s+(%S+)")
level = tonumber(level)
 good = good=="true"
print(level,good,message)
print(type(level),type(good),type(message))
```

The pattern in `match` skips the first field and captures the following three fields; fields are separated by whitespace.